# Laravel nested comments ( 3 level deep ) with pagination?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, nested-loops

would like a general idea ( Database schema, functions etc ) required to code nested comments ( 3 level deep ) with pagination ( 5 comments per page ) in Laravel,

I have `image` table and a `comment` table where `users` table can post many `comments` to the `image`

the `comment` table look like this:

```
id   | user_id | image_id |  _lft  |  _rgt  |     comment     | parent_id | depth |
1    |    1    |    1     |    0   |    0   |   Test Coment   |    NULL   |   0   |
2    |    2    |    1     |    0   |    0   |   Test Coment2  |      1    |   0   |
3    |    1    |    1     |    0   |    0   |   Test Coment3  |      2    |   0   |
4    |    1    |    1     |    0   |    0   |   Test Coment4  |      3    |   0   |
```

I tried recursive functions for the `comments` but it does not work with the pagination.

For example:

there is `1` Level 0 comment with `4` Level 1 nested comments ( 5 comments total ), but the pagination only considers `level 0` `comments`, so any comment that is nested deeper than `level 0` wont be accounted for.

I want the pagination to show 5 comments ( `1` level 0 `comment` + `4` nested level 1 `comment` ) instead of 5x level 0 comment + all nested comments.

If this is possible, say if there is `1` `level 0 comment` with `6` nested `level 1 comment`, is it possible to break it into pagination like `page 1` = `1` `level 0 comment` + `4` nested `level 1 comment` and `page 2` = `2` nested `level 1 comment`?